# Format time as "24-hour Military Time"?

Tags: sql-server-2008, time, datetime-format

I am updating some SQL Server 2000 code to SQL Server 2008R2, and there is function that looks a lot like [this](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Military_Time_Format) for converting the time into 24 hour format. What is a cooler/more clever way to do that in T-SQL?

Comment: It would help if examples of desired output were posted.

Comment: Links to external sites that ask your question aren't acceptable, because if the external site goes down or disappears your question becomes meaningless. Also, they're not searchable - the content isn't here. Please edit your post and put the actual question in it, and as  @pst said post the sample output you're trying to obtain and information on the source of the "time" you're using (for instance, is it from an actual `DATETIME` column, or is it from a `CHAR/VARCHAR` column?). Please remember we know absolutely nothing about your data or code other than what you tell us here. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If all you want is just military time:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) AS MilitaryTime
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want time till second, then use this:

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) 'hh:mi:ss'
```

IF you want time till millisecond, then use this:

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GETDATE(),114) 'hh:mi:ss:mmm'
```

`GETDATE()` is used for current date you can pass any variable here.